# A database table is not associated with any other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I have a query below where a user will type in a term from a question and it will output questions which contains that term and with it, it will display associated with the question it's answer, its option type, it's reply type etc.

Below is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT q.QuestionContent, o.OptionType, q.NoofAnswers, 
                GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Answer SEPARATOR '') AS Answer, 
                r.ReplyType, q.QuestionMarks, q.SessionId   
FROM Answer an    
JOIN Question q 
ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId 
AND an.SessionId = q.SessionId   
JOIN Reply r 
ON q.ReplyId = r.ReplyId    
JOIN Option_Table o 
ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId 
WHERE ".implode(" AND ", array_fill(0, $numTerms, "q.QuestionContent LIKE ?"))."
GROUP BY an.SessionId, an.QuestionId
```

Now I realise that by using CRON, every year it will delete previous Exams (SessionId) meaning that these questions will not appear for the user to search in the user.

So what I wanted to do was set up a table where it stores all previous questions, the table is below:

```
Previous_Question Table:

PreviousId (auto) PreviousContent
1                 What is 2+2? 
2                 What is 4+4 and 3+3?
3                 What is square root of 144?
```

So I want to use the Previous_Question Table to be able to search for previous questions. so I need to change query above The biggest problem though is that this table does not link to any other table, meaning that how am I going to be able to retrieve it's correct Answer, Reply Type, Option Type etc? This is my problem.

Any help?

EDIT:

Below are the other tables:

Question Table

```
SessionId QuestionId  QuestionContent             NoofAnswers ReplyId QuestionMarks OptionId
AAA       1           What is 2+2?                  1          1          5         2
AAA       2           What is 4+4 and 3+3?          1          2          5         3
ABC       3           What is square root of 144?   1          1          7         5
```

Answer Table:

```
AnswerId(auto) SessionId QuestionId  Answer
1              AAA       1           B
2              AAA       2           A
3              AAA       3           D
4              ABC       1           A
```

Reply Table:

```
ReplyId ReplyType
1       Single
2       Multiple
```

Option Table:

```
OptionId  OptionType
1         A-C
2         A-D
3         A-E
4         A-F
5         A-G
```

Now lets say that SessionId "AAA" get deleted, that means all of the corresponding rows which contains "AAA" for SessionId  in "Question" table will be deleted. But just realised that so would the corresponding answers.

I need to help on somehow set up something where it will store previous questions and its details (Answers, Reply Type, Option Type) etc so that even though questions and answers are deleted because their session has been deleted, that the teacher can some how pick out those questions which are stored somewhere so the teacher can still be selecting those questions and their relevant answers, options type, reply type etc.

Comment: After reading it 3 times, I still don't get your question. Would you mind to explain what's in the different tables?

Comment: @BurninLeo Lemme edit question and show you other table details. Give me 5 mins

Comment: If you want previous questions why delete them?

Comment: @davidstrachan The problem is that if an exam (session) is deleted, everything that is associated with that exam will be removed from the database meaning no questions from those exams will be displayed. Now if I don't remove the relevant questions and answers associated with the deleted exam, problem is that, that sessionId could be used in the future, and then big problem is that I can have duplicates in "Question" Table as I will have the same sessionId (Exam Name) and same QuestionId (question number). Both these fields are primary keys in "Question" Table

Comment: Is it just my lack of understanding mySQL, or would the non-aggregate columns still contain 'random' results (despite the presence of the `ORDER BY`)?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Your right there, the ORDER BY is not really needed

Comment: So... you're just accepting what are undefined results in non-grouped, non-aggregated columns?  That strikes me as dangerous, to say the least - besides which, you have both `GROUP BY` _and_ `DISTINCT`, you should only need one of them (having both means you're doing something oddball).

Comment: I need to reconstrut my tables, especially primary keys, I shouldn't of gave the current primary keys any meaning, I just auto increment primary keys for all my tables really to solve this

Comment: Why not just filter out old exams if you don't want them displayed? This would be far easier than deleting them.

Comment: How can I filter out old exams in database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick shot... you can either change the structure of your session table and add a bool field, let's say "active". Then, run a query over that table, and set active to TRUE.
And, instead of delete the session, just change the value to inactive. So next time when you need to, just check if active=TRUE.